# Compare Two Arrays and Show False Indexes in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm coding a similar algorithm game with jQuery sortable function. I've coded some parts. I'm ordering list and comparing two arrays. If person can do true order (so Algorithm if true) program showing a message.
**NOW**, i need if list ordering and my algortithm ordering true (comparing), true list item texts turn to **GREEN**, if false turn to **RED**.
My code:

```js
  //pageonload mix ordering
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var parent = $("#algoritma");
    var divs = parent.children();
    while (divs.length) {
      parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }

  });

  //when list ordering update
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.algList').sortable({
      connectWith: '.algList',
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var liste = this.id;
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        var sira = order.join(';');
        var trueOrder = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
        var trueSira = trueOrder.join(';');
        console.log(order);
        console.log(trueOrder);

        //compare arrays
        if (JSON.stringify(order) === JSON.stringify(trueOrder)) {
          console.log('They are equal! Congratulations');
        } else {
        
          //i need this part. if two array not equal ordering, true list texts turn to GREEN color and false list texts turn RED color 
          
        }


      }
    });
  });
```

```css
  body {
    margin: auto;
    width: 600px;
  }

  #algoritma {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 35px;
  }

  li {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
  
  <ul id="algoritma" class="algList">
    <li id="1">Step #1</li>
    <li id="2">Step #2</li>
    <li id="3">Step #3</li>
    <li id="4">Step #4</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the direct array equals check and do something like this

```js
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.algList').sortable({
      connectWith: '.algList',
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var liste = this.id;
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        var sira = order.join(';');
        var trueOrder = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
        var trueSira = trueOrder.join(';');
        console.log(order);
        console.log(trueOrder);

        //compare arrays
        for (let i=0; i < order.length; i++) {
            if (trueOrder[i] === order[i]) {
                document.getElementById(i+1).style.color = 'green';
            } else {
                document.getElementById(i+1).style.color = 'red';
            }
        }

      }
    });
  });
```

Also to avoid a case in which initial order is not the correct order we can do something like this. Make a new string which just stores the order. If the value of this string is `'1234'`, then empty the parent and randomize again.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let parent = $("#algoritma");
    let divs = parent.children();
    let randomOrder = '';
    while (divs.length) {
      const randomDiv = divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0];
      randomOrder += randomDiv.id;
      parent.append(randomDiv);
      if (randomOrder === '1234') {
        divs = parent.children();
        parent.empty();
        randomOrder = '';
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: that was perfect man, thank you. last problem; when page load program mixing list but if it will be correct order? how to avoid this thing? it must never be in true order when page load

Comment: Hi @ozan , I have edited the answer to include that changes too. Now the initial order will never be same as true order. Also if this answer has helped, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer. :)

Comment: Hi @ozan, I did not understand your requirement clearly. Can you post the code for the test button ?

Comment: You can add `$("#btn").attr("disabled", false);` at line 12 in your fiddle code. This will make sure that every time you change order, the button is enabled again